# Google translation of English subtitles gives other Chinese words - what exactly was said, what dialect?

Tags: translation

I wanted to listen to the words as spoken by other person, but Google translation of English subtitles gave other Chinese words (by sounds).

What exactly was said (Chinese characters), what dialect? Why translation gave almost all differently?

Subtitles "fulfillment, happiness and security", translation by google to traditional (for simplified voice sounded the same) 充實，幸福和安全
Chōngshí, xìngfú hé ānquán.

Original: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rKn--8Dy9O8&t=466

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“获得感、幸福感、安全感” were the exact Mandarin words spoken by Xi Jinping. Google doesn’t necessarily translate based on context, and often translates word-for-word, garbling up the meaning of the entire sentence.

Comment: thank you! Could you advice good dictionary where I can find most correct meaning of e.g. these words? Chinese to English and/or meanings of words explained by other Chinese words (forgot term for that)

Comment: You could use Oxford English-Chinese Dictionary

Comment: but I need the opposite way now...

Comment: I think there are two sections, one EN-CN and the other CN-EN